# Configure Eclipse CDT or Codeblocks to get LLVM IR intellisense

Tags: c++, eclipse, llvm, codeblocks

I want to configure Eclipse (or Codeblocks) so that when I write a pass, I can at least take advantage of Intellisense (even if building passes directly from within Eclipse is not possible). **Update: I am getting at least some intellisense once I enabled *Parsing-based Proposals* in Eclipse (details below)**

So far I have configured Eclipse to use clang to compile simple C++ programs.

To get intellisense for LLVM pass, I added `/usr/local/include` to *Includes* directories and tried code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <llvm/IR/Function.h>

using namespace std:
int main() {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't fail on `#include <llvm/IR/Function.h>` itself (i.e. it can find this header file), but upon including subsequent files, gives me

```
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h:58:3: error: "Must #define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS before #including Support/DataTypes.h"
```

Any pointers to how I could make it give me intellisense at least?

**Complete Log**

```
01:22:48 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project HelloWorld2 ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
clang++ -I/usr/local/include -O0 -emit-llvm -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o src/HelloWorld2.bc ../src/HelloWorld2.cpp 
In file included from ../src/HelloWorld2.cpp:10:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Function.h:22:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Argument.h:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/Twine.h:14:
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h:58:3: error: "Must #define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS before #including Support/DataTypes.h"
# error "Must #define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS before #including Support/DataTypes.h"
  ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h:62:3: error: "Must #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS before "         "#including Support/DataTypes.h"
# error "Must #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS before " \
  ^
In file included from ../src/HelloWorld2.cpp:10:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Function.h:22:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Argument.h:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Attributes.h:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/ArrayRef.h:14:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h:20:
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/MathExtras.h:273:24: error: use of undeclared identifier 'INT64_C'
  return N >= 64 || (-(INT64_C(1)<<(N-1)) <= x && x < (INT64_C(1)<<(N-1)));
                       ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/MathExtras.h:273:56: error: use of undeclared identifier 'INT64_C'
  return N >= 64 || (-(INT64_C(1)<<(N-1)) <= x && x < (INT64_C(1)<<(N-1)));
                                                       ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/MathExtras.h:299:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UINT64_C'
  return N >= 64 || x < (UINT64_C(1)<<(N));
                         ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/MathExtras.h:331:24: error: use of undeclared identifier 'INT64_C'
  return N >= 64 || (-(INT64_C(1)<<(N-1)) <= x && x < (INT64_C(1)<<(N-1)));
                       ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/MathExtras.h:331:56: error: use of undeclared identifier 'INT64_C'
  return N >= 64 || (-(INT64_C(1)<<(N-1)) <= x && x < (INT64_C(1)<<(N-1)));
                                                       ^
In file included from ../src/HelloWorld2.cpp:10:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Function.h:22:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Argument.h:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Attributes.h:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/ArrayRef.h:14:
/usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h:232:20: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  void push_back(T &&Elt) {
                   ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h:476:33: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  iterator insert(iterator I, T &&Elt) {
                                ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h:645:46: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  SmallVectorImpl &operator=(SmallVectorImpl &&RHS);
                                             ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h:383:12: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
      for (auto I = this->end(), E = this->begin() + N; I != E; ++I)
           ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h:764:70: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
SmallVectorImpl<T> &SmallVectorImpl<T>::operator=(SmallVectorImpl<T> &&RHS) {
                                                                     ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h:878:27: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  SmallVector(SmallVector &&RHS) : SmallVectorImpl<T>(N) {
                          ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h:883:44: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  const SmallVector &operator=(SmallVector &&RHS) {
                                           ^
In file included from ../src/HelloWorld2.cpp:10:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Function.h:22:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Argument.h:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Attributes.h:20:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/FoldingSet.h:21:
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:134:70: error: expected expression
          BumpPtrAllocatorImpl<AllocatorT, SlabSize, SizeThreshold>> {
                                                                     ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:346:2: error: expected a type
};
 ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:346:2: error: expected class name
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:346:2: error: expected '{' after base class list
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:362:53: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  SpecificBumpPtrAllocator(SpecificBumpPtrAllocator &&Old)
                                                    ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:366:64: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  SpecificBumpPtrAllocator &operator=(SpecificBumpPtrAllocator &&RHS) {
                                                               ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:375:5: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    auto DestroyElements = [](char *Begin, char *End) {
    ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:375:28: error: expected expression
    auto DestroyElements = [](char *Begin, char *End) {
                           ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:381:10: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (auto I = Allocator.Slabs.begin(), E = Allocator.Slabs.end(); I != E;
         ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:381:29: error: no member named 'Slabs' in 'llvm::BumpPtrAllocatorImpl<llvm::MallocAllocator, 4096, 4096>'
    for (auto I = Allocator.Slabs.begin(), E = Allocator.Slabs.end(); I != E;
                  ~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:381:58: error: no member named 'Slabs' in 'llvm::BumpPtrAllocatorImpl<llvm::MallocAllocator, 4096, 4096>'
    for (auto I = Allocator.Slabs.begin(), E = Allocator.Slabs.end(); I != E;
                                               ~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:383:52: error: no member named 'computeSlabSize' in 'llvm::BumpPtrAllocatorImpl<llvm::MallocAllocator, 4096, 4096>'
      size_t AllocatedSlabSize = BumpPtrAllocator::computeSlabSize(
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:384:35: error: no member named 'Slabs' in 'llvm::BumpPtrAllocatorImpl<llvm::MallocAllocator, 4096, 4096>'
          std::distance(Allocator.Slabs.begin(), I));
                        ~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:386:35: error: no member named 'Slabs' in 'llvm::BumpPtrAllocatorImpl<llvm::MallocAllocator, 4096, 4096>'
      char *End = *I == Allocator.Slabs.back() ? Allocator.CurPtr
                        ~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:386:60: error: no member named 'CurPtr' in 'llvm::BumpPtrAllocatorImpl<llvm::MallocAllocator, 4096, 4096>'
      char *End = *I == Allocator.Slabs.back() ? Allocator.CurPtr
                                                 ~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:392:10: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (auto &PtrAndSize : Allocator.CustomSizedSlabs) {
         ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:392:39: error: no member named 'CustomSizedSlabs' in 'llvm::BumpPtrAllocatorImpl<llvm::MallocAllocator, 4096, 4096>'
    for (auto &PtrAndSize : Allocator.CustomSizedSlabs) {
                            ~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Allocator.h:392:27: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (auto &PtrAndSize : Allocator.CustomSizedSlabs) {
                          ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
13 warnings and 20 errors generated.

01:22:50 Build Finished (took 1s.509ms)
```

**UPDATE:** Eclipse does give me intellisense (at least some of it), I had to check *Parsing-based Proposals* in *Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced* (It was unchecked by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not answering the question directly, but it will ensure, you have a correctly working build environment. It is specific for code blocks.

First checkout the source tree of llvm (directly taken from the getting started [guide](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#git-mirror)):

```
git clone http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git
cd llvm/tools
git clone http://llvm.org/git/clang.git
cd .. 
cd projects
git clone http://llvm.org/git/compiler-rt.git
git clone http://llvm.org/git/libcxx.git
git clone http://llvm.org/git/libcxxabi.git
git clone http://llvm.org/git/test-suite.git
git clone http://llvm.org/git/openmp.git
```

Remove anything you don't like.

Then create an directory outside the llvm directory:

```
 cd ..
 mkdir build
```

Change your directory (cd) to there and run:

```
 cd build 
 cmake -g "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" <your configure options> ../llvm
```

Assuming llvm shares the root path, otherwise change the ../llvm line to the correct path. Then open it as an existing project in code::blocks.

If all went well, your build environment is setup correctly and code completion should work.

Comment: Thank you @edgar-klerks, While it may not answer the question directly, It does solve a related problem, I am accepting it.